# How can I push the items to an array field schema in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What im trying to do is to push the location and the status of the user in an array in a Schema.
The reason I'm doing that is to store all the user locations in a schema(like a history location)
When I create a location I use the method `findOneAndUpdate()`.

controller/auth.js

```
exports.addLocation = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const {phone, locations, status} = req.body;

  const theLocation = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { phone },
    { locations, status },
    { new: false }
  )

  res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      msg: "A location as been created",
      data: theLocation
  })
})
```

models/User.js

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({

  phone: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
  },

  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  
  code: {
    type: Number,
    max: 4
  },

  fullName: {
    type:String
  },

  gender: {
    type:String
  },

  birthdate: {
    type:String
  },

  locations: [
    {
      location: {
        latitude: {type:Number},
        longitude: {type:Number},
      },

      status: {
        type: String
      },
    
      createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
      }
    }
  ],
});
```

So when a new item is stored, the previous one is deleted.

How can I save the previous item to another MongoDB field?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$push` at your query like:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { phone: "0912341234" },
    {
        $push: {
            locations: {
                location: {
                    latitude: 10,
                    longitude: 10,
                },
                status: "online",
            },
        },
    },
    { new: true },
);
```